# Should I capitalise these words or not?

Tags: capitalization

> Say hello to **aunt** Jane.
>
> Say hello to **Aunt** Jane.
>
> Dear **Uncle** Sam.
>
> Dear **uncle** Sam.

Should I capitalise these word or not? Why?

Answer (score 2):

When directly associated with a proper name, they are capitalized

> Aunt Jane
>   Uncle Sam

you can think of it as part of their name.

When used alone, they may or may not be capitalized

> my Aunt
>   my Uncle
>   my aunt
>   my uncle

in the same way that Mommy or Daddy are capitalized.

Comment: So Cookie Monster is wrong? In my examples the only possible answer is to capitalise these words? Can I write them in small letters? Or is it wrong?

Comment: I would not say Cookie Monster is wrong. If I am specifically referring to my Mother's brother, I use "Uncle". I only have one uncle (notice the lower case) and I consider it his "name" when addressing him as in "How are you today Uncle?" I would never write "uncle James", it would be "Uncle James". However, there might be a convention of "uncles" in town. As an aside, I've also only used "Auntie" to address my Uncle's wife.

Comment: I would go so far say that Cookie Monster is wrong and this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. Because in English we only capitalize titles. For example:

> The **President** of Russia Vladimir Putin is going to meet with **President Barack Obama** this Sunday to discuss a much-needed and long-awaited peaceful solution to the Syria crisis.

Here, *aunt* and *uncle* are not personal titles or titles of office as in the example above.

Personal titles such as *Miss*, *Mrs.*, *Ms.*, *Ma'am* etc. are capitalized.

---

By the way, if you mean Uncle Sam as that guy from the posters, the entire thing is written in all caps because it's a proper noun then.

Comment: What about these examples?:
https://books.google.pl/books?id=miFoGevUdM0C&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=%22Say+hello+to+Aunt%22&source=bl&ots=g-HxpJTWqp&sig=n7Deg6xDpJe3QGHk_O73oaciXgA&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvu__G247OAhWCWBQKHYjPCigQ6AEIOzAI#v=onepage&q=%22Say%20hello%20to%20Aunt%22&f=false

https://books.google.pl/books?id=Lkp0OXLB5UoC&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=%22Say+hello+to+Aunt%22&source=bl&ots=TRhePI3jQX&sig=ynGh8HX-NFgRiUY7AeWup6Symcc&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvu__G247OAhWCWBQKHYjPCigQ6AEIQDAJ#v=onepage&q=%22Say%20hello%20to%20Aunt%22&f=false

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. I don't know. I sent this question to my friend (he's got a college degree in English literature or something). Maybe he will be able to definitively answer this question.

Comment: He said that my answer is correct.

Comment: You don't capitalize *aunt/uncle* when you say something like *my aunt*; however, in the case of *Aunt Jane/Uncle Sam*, you do capitalize them. Thy're treated like proper nouns.